# How do i make the whole tile(.ie the tab in the nav menu) part of the hyperlink

Tags: css

I have made this nav menu based on the Windows 8 concept.
i now want that the whole tile becomes part of the hyperlink. So then if we click anywhere on the tile it will take us to the linked site.
Code is here on JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Lkdy/

```
 // html 
       <div class="div1">
           <ul>
            <li><a href="ITEM1.html">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <a href="#"><li>Item 3</a></li>
             <a href="#"><li>Item 4</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>

// css 
.div1 {list-style: none;
    margin-left:14%;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    margin-top:auto;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;}
.div1 li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 3em;
    color: #000;
    font-family: "Open Sans","Century Gothic","Trebuchet MS","Ubuntu","sans-serif";
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18pt;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    width:85px;
}
.div1 ul li:hover{
    padding: 80px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.div1 ul li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.div1:hover ul:hover li{
    opacity:0.5;
}
.div1:hover ul:hover li:hover{
    opacity:10;
}
.div1 ul li:nth-of-type(1){
    background:#CB4F1E;
}
.div1 ul li:nth-of-type(2){
    background:#D3711B; 
}
.div1 ul li:nth-of-type(3){
    background:#94B339; 
}
.div1 ul li:nth-of-type(4){
     background:#68B43F;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .div1 {
        position: relative ;
        min-height: 70px;
    }   
    .div1 ul {
        width: 180px;
        padding: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        left: 0;
        border: solid 1px #aaa;
        background: url("threelines_48_3.png") no-repeat 10px 11px;
        background-position:left 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        opacity:1;
        min-height: 40px;
    }
    .div1 li {
        display: none; /* hide all <li> items */
        margin: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .div1 ul:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0);
        background:transparent;
        border: 0px solid #000;
    }
    .div1 ul:hover li {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 5px;
        opacity: 1;
        height: 20px;
        padding:4px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .div1 ul li{
        width:180px;
        padding:4px;
        margin-top:2px;
        opacity:1;
        height:20px;
    }
    .div1 ul li:hover{
        opacity: 1;
        height:20px;
        padding:4px;
        text-align: center;
    }
.div1 ul li:nth-of-type(1){
    background:#CB4F1E;
}
.div1 ul li:nth-of-type(2){
    background:#D3711B; 
}
.div1 ul li:nth-of-type(3){
    background:#94B339; 
}
.div1 ul li:nth-of-type(4){
     background:#68B43F;
}
}
```

formatted.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M9nrL/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hwn8K/)**

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="item1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="item2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="item3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="item4"><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {margin:0; padding:0; }
ul { width:400px; float:left }
li { float:left; list-style:none;}
li a { display:block;  width:200px; height:200px; }

li.item1 a { background:red; }
li.item2 a { background:orange; }
li.item3 a { background:lime; }
li.item4 a { background:blue; }

li a:hover { opacity:0.5;}
```

**Explanation**:

By default the `a` element is `inline`, so if you want to give it a `height` and `width` then you need to make it either `display:block` or `display:inline-block` for the `height/width` to actually work and make the whole thing clickable.

Comment: ok thanks but how do i then make my text in the center of the tile??

Comment: @user2466239 Horizontally centred, or horizontally and vertically centred? if the latter, replace the current `li a` rule with `li a { width:200px; height:200px; display: table-cell; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle}` - **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwn8K/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid HTML. I have corrected it here: http://jsfiddle.net/M9nrL/2/

```
<div class="div1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="ITEM1.html">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And added this CSS:

```
.div1 ul li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    line-height: 100%;
}
```

The `a` element is defaulted to `inline`, which means its height and width are the lenght and height of the text inside it. But by setting display to `block`, the elements(`a`) height and width are set to its parent(`li`).

Also added `line-height : 100%;` to vertically align your text. (This will only work if your text fits in a single line)